# VBA Macro, Current selected cell and next cell in row

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I am trying to write a VBA Macro to apply conditional formatting which does the following:

If the currently selected cell is not equal to the cell to the right, change fill colour. So far I have this:

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Range("G17:J17").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=$K$17"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
End Sub
```

The problem lies in the range `("G17:J17")`, which is a merged cell, and the formula `("$K$17")`.

It should be `Range("G$CurrentRow:J$CurrentRow")` and `Formula1:="=$K$CurrentRow"` but I just don't know the syntax.

Sorry for the noobish question, but I'm a PLC programmer, not an excel guy. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: `Range("G17:J17")` should probably be `activeCell.offset(0,1)` assuming you are selecting any cell in `G` column. If you don't then you may want to tweak that - look up [ActiveCell() property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. It's just the Formula that is baffling me now

Comment: try `"=$K$" & activecell.row`

Comment: I could kiss you, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range("G17:J17")` should probably be `activeCell.offset(0,1)` assuming you are selecting any cell in G column.

If you don't then you may want to tweak that - look up [ActiveCell() property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673(v=office.15).aspx) - it basically returns the currently activated cell(s) as a `Range()` object

The formula could then be `"=$K$" & activecell.row`